# Can you increase your chances of getting imposter?

Tags: among-us

I have heard (and witnessed) that rapidly switching your player color in Among Us before you get into a game increases your chances of getting imposter. I witnessed my friend get imposter 4 times in a row a few weeks ago with this strategy.

I know it could be a total fluke that he got imposter 4 times in a row, but part of me actually believes this strategy works.

**Is it true that color swapping before getting into a game in Among Us increases your chances of getting imposter?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you cannot artificially elevate your chances of being selected as Imposter over other people. The exact logic of becoming an imposter, as described by the [Among Us Impostor wikia page](https://among-us.fandom.com/wiki/Impostor) is “The chance of a player being an Impostor is 100 multiplied by the number of impostors divided by the number of players.” This is absolute, and cannot be changed via in-game methods.

Playing in a  lobby of fewer than ten people, or playing in lobbies with three impostors will increase your chances of becoming impostor overall. As an example, playing in a ten-person with two imposters gives you a 1/5 chance of being selected as imposter, whereas playing in a nine-person lobby with three imposters give you 1/3 chance of being selected. Still, as I said, all other players in that lobby have an equal chance of being imposter.

In reference to your friend being selected four times in a row, in a typical 10-person, 2 imposter game that has a 0.1% ((1/5)^4 odds) chance of happening. Unlikely, but not impossible and not indicative of artificially elevating a players' chance of becoming an imposter.

Comment: About the 'can't be random because of streaks' point, I've often heard that True random can be weirdly streaky. Like flip a coin 100 times, the chances you got a 6-7 streak in there are pretty high.

Comment: A friend of mine was 7 times imposter in a row before even chosen as crewmate once

Answer (score 3):

**No.** It's completely random.

Sure you could use hacks, but that's terrible sportsmanship, and makes the game less fun for others. I (as have many other people) struggled with getting Impostor in Among Us, but there is no viable way to increase your chances. Impostor is 2/10 chance on a 10 person, 2 impostor server.

If you want a good, viable way of increasing your chance of being Impostor you can do the following: Use two devices to increase that chance to 4/10, play on a 3 Impostor server, make an Among Us hack, or play with friends on a private server where you don't have to worry about too many other things and can have fun.

The other advice I have for those still unhappy, just play the game. Deal with not being Impostor. It's just a game, and Impostor isn't the best part of it. You don't *always* have to be the one who gets to kill, as it's fun to be the people to investigate what was happening, and vote out those who aren't exactly doing tasks.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I speculate it's because it doesn't add new information that the previous answer mentioned apart from the mention of hacks. The hack information may be considered not useful to some, and some people do have a negative reaction when they see the word 'hack' thrown around.

Comment: What's the problem with a reference to hacking? It's infinitely more common than not.

Comment: I wonder how the game would be affected if players could publicly indicate whether they wished to be impostor more or less often (with a bias of up to e.g. 3:1)?  The players who like being impostor could then be impostors more often, but at the expense of being more highly suspected.  Those whose probability is set lower wouldn't be impostor as often, but might be able to win more easily because the crew would be less likely to suspect them.

Answer (score 0):

Swapping colors may increase your chances, because I have heard of it, too. But in terms, this is an **exploit**.

This is the safest and official way to increase your chances of getting **Imposter**:

> Currently, Among Us lets up to three players be Imposters per game if you adjust this in the game's setting. The number of Imposters can also be set to 1 or 2, but having more imposters increases your chances of becoming one. ... Simply open the Game Tab and increase the "# Impostors" to 3 by selecting the + symbol.

In short words, increase your **Imposter** setting to 3. This will change your chances from 10% (depending on what setting you chose) to 30%. What makes 3 imposters not make the game fun is that if you kill a body and the crewmates vote out a innocent person, you either win or get a one-kill.

Comment: Do **NOT** increase impostor count to three. Its not fun and its basically a lure for impostor wars, if someone doesnt become impostor then ALL the crewmates will leave and rejoin constantly in hopes of impostor rank. But it totally defeats the purpose because other players will end up doing the same.

Comment: This is incorrect, the OP may play with friends and family and this might be common, but this answer depends, increasing imposter count to three increases their chances, and we never discussed about what and what not crewmates will do, because the OP never mentioned this. @mindstormsboi

Comment: You may include your opinion in your own answer.

Comment: @Wabbit. answers shouldn't address other answers besides for very minimally, that is best left as a comment

Answer (score -4):

These are not proven to be true but ways to get imposter “more often” are:

- Spamming the use button in the lobby.
- Changing your hat or colors
  quickly in the lobby.
- Using hats and colors such as black, blue, Jason mask, plague doctor mask.

However, I do not think these are true even though some YouTubers have said they are, you can try them for yourself if you like.

Comment: https://youtu.be/8uPmeWiFTIw